# How do i insert a image in a database and be able to show it again?

Tags: php, html, sql, database, image

I am trying to insert a image in a database and then show it again.
At the moment it doesn't work. 
So my question is how to insert a image and then show it on the page.

Tried insert and select but it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want upload and show files with php try it:

1) First you will upload your file to a folder. [This tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) may be help you for upload file with PHP.

2) Create a table named like *"uploaded_files"* on your database and create fields under the table like "*id*, *file_url*".

3) Save ***$target_file*** value to ***file_url*** field during upload process and get it from db.

But if you want use blob for keep files in your database [this tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-mysql-blob/) may be can help you.

---

Try it on php:

```
CREATE TABLE `uploaded_files` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `file_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Connect your database named as 'db_conenct.php':

```
<?php
// Database configuration
$dbHost     = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "user";
$dbPassword = "pass";
$dbName     = "your_database_name";

// Create database connection
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

// Check connection
if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
}
?>
```

Create upload form with HTML, you will send your data to upload.php with "POST" method:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select Image File to Upload:
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
// Include the database configuration file
include 'db_connect.php';
$statusMsg = '';

// File upload path
$targetDir = "uploads/";
$fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
$fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
    // Allow certain file formats
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif','pdf');
    if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
        // Upload file to server
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){
            // Insert image file name into database
            $insert = $db->query("INSERT into uploaded_files (file_url) VALUES ('".$fileName."'");
            if($insert){
                $statusMsg = "The file ".$fileName. " has been uploaded successfully.";
            }else{
                $statusMsg = "File upload failed, please try again.";
            } 
        }else{
            $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }else{
        $statusMsg = 'Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, & PDF files are allowed to upload.';
    }
}else{
    $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.';
}

// Display status message
echo $statusMsg;
?>
```

Show uploaded images:

```
<?php
// Include the database configuration file
include 'db_connect.php';

// Get images from the database
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM uploaded_files ORDER BY id DESC");

if($query->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        $imageURL = 'uploads/'.$row["file_url"];
?>
    <img src="<?php echo $imageURL; ?>" alt="" />
<?php }
}else{ ?>
    <p>No image(s) found...</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know If I understand your question well but anyway I try answer it.

In my opinion there are two ways how to do it:

1. Upload your image to any cloud storing images or to your project structure and save in database only path of image.
2. Get file content and then save it to your database, eg.

```
$file = fopen($MY_FILE, 'r');
$file_contents = fread($file, filesize($MY_FILE));
fclose($file);

/* escape some stcharacters in file_contents before query.*/
$file_contents = addslashes($file_contents);

// Add the file in the database
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die("Unable to connect to database.");
mysql_select_db('test') or die("Unable to select the DB.");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO files SET file_data='$file_contents'") or die("MySQL Query Error: " . mysql_error() . "

". "The SQL was: $SQL

");
mysql_close();
echo "File INSERTED into files table successfully.";
```

To store file binary content in database, column must be one of these types:

- TINYBLOB
- BLOB
- MEDIUMBLOB
- LONGBLOB

Comment: `mysql_query` does not exist. It has been removed!